# How to safeguard a SQL alias against being NULL

Tags: sql, sum

Although I'm using iBatis for o/r mapping here, this is definitely a pure SQL question. I only mention iBatis so as to provide full context.

I have a table `items..fruits`:

```
fruit_id    fruit_name      fruit_color     fruit_cost
=====================================================
1           apple           red             12
2           pear            brown           70
3           apple           green           18
...
6485        banana          yellow          30
6486        plum            purple          <null>
6487        kiwi            green           85
```

Please note: for reasons outside of my control, `fruit_cost` is nullable.

I have an iBatis SQL query that sums up the cost of all fruits in the table (by name):

```
SELECT
    sum(item_cost) AS fruitSum
FROM
    items..fruits
WHERE
    fruit_name = #{value}#
```

As you can see, when we run this query for `apple`, the returned `fruitSum` will be 30 (12 + 18). But when we run it for `plum` we get NULL (and actually, in my full code, I get `net.sf.cglib.beans.BulkBeanException`s, but that doesn't really matter here).

I'm wondering if there's some SQL magic I can sprinkle onto my query to force `fruitSum` to be zero (0) if it would otherwise be null. So, something like this:

```
SELECT
    sum(item_cost) AS fruitSum DEFAULT 0
FROM
    items..fruits
WHERE
    fruit_name = #{value}#
```

Comment: which relational database flavor are you using?

Comment: Try to uSe NVL function.

Comment: So 20 is the new 30, huh? :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : Oh Snap !!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is standard SQL, then use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(item_cost), 0) AS fruitSum
FROM   items.fruits
WHERE  fruit_name = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    sum(NVL(item_cost, 0)) AS fruitSum
FROM
    items..fruits
WHERE
    fruit_name = #{value}#
```